# Why is Class.getAnnotation() requiring me to do a cast?

Tags: java

I'm using Java 1.6.0_25.

I have an annotation defined:

```
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Resource {
    String value();
}
```

And later when I use getAnnotation:

```
Resource resource = (Resource)cls.getAnnotation(Resource.class);
```

the compiler and IDE agree that I must cast the result, but getAnnotation is declared in the Java 1.5 documentation as:

```
public <A extends Annotation> A getAnnotation(Class<A> annotationClass);
```

Since Resource.class is of type Class, it seems to me that this means that cls.getAnnotation(Resource.class) should return type Resource, and I should need to cast.

All examples I've found using getAnnotation don't have a cast, so I must be doing something wrong.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

What is the type of `cls`? Is it raw `Class` or is it `Class<Something>`?

If it's the raw type `Class`, then the cast is necessary. If you make it at least `Class<?>` instead of `Class`, you won't need the cast anymore.

```
Class cls = Example.class;

// Error: Type mismatch, cannot convert from Annotation to Resource
Resource anno = cls.getAnnotation(Resource.class);

Class<?> cls2 = Example.class;
Resource anno = cls2.getAnnotation(Resource.class); // OK

Class<Example> cls3 = Example.class;
Resource anno = cls3.getAnnotation(Resource.class); // OK
```

Comment: This works but out of curiosity: why doesn't the first line compile? The getAnnotation method doesn't use the T of Class<T> at all so it should not make any difference? (it obviously does!!)

Comment: I think that when you use the raw class `Class`, the compiler forgets about all generics in the class for backward compatibility with pre-generics Java.

Comment: Definitely worked.  Seems odd, but I guess @Jesper is right that it is for backwards-compatibility.